# how to set attribute values from ajax return data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I have a situation where I display a number of  tags from the data returned from ajax script. I have a another  tag already existing on the jsp which accepts values onClick of each link. 
The problem is that the onclick attribute of the  is not getting set when tag is created by jquery append.

here is the code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getResults").click(function(){

     $.post("getRefineSearchResultsPath", {bug:bug}, function(data) {

    var value = "<div id='list' class='attachment'>";
    value += "<ul class='unstyled'>";
    $issue.find('attachment').each(function(){

    var $attachment = $(this);
    value += "<li>";
    value += "<a href='#' onclick='document.f1.attachmentName.value='" +$attachment.find('attachmentName').text(); 
    value += "';document.f1.issueKey.value='"+$attachment.find('attachmentissueKey').text();
    value += "';document.f1.digest.value='"+$attachment.find('attachmentdigest').text();
    value += "';document.f1.submit();'>"+$attachment.find('attachmentName').text();
                                value += "</a>";
                                value += "</li>";
    });

    value +="</ul>";
    value +="</div>";

    $("#result").append(value);
    });
    });

});
```

My JSP is here:-

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="getResults" type="button" class="btn">Get</button>

<form name=f1 action="fetchAttachments" method="POST">
                    <input name=attachmentName type=hidden value=undefined> <input
                        name=issueKey type=hidden value=undefined> <input
                        name=digest type=hidden value=undefined>
                </form>

<div id="result">
&nbsp;
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically on each link click the form should get submitted. 
This works fine if I use JSTL to render results on JSP 
But doesn't work when i get data result via Ajax in the form of xml. 
In all the onclick attribute is not getting set. 
Any idea what can be the reason?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what is generated

```
<a href='#' onclick='document.f1.attachmentName.value='" +$attachment.find('attachmentName').text();
```

when it is rendered it is

```
<a href='#' onclick='document.f1.attachmentName.value='someText'
```

You have a quotes issue.